# Please help me print this array to my email- zend_mail

Tags: zend-framework, zend-mail

I'm so dang close.  I'm trying to print the contents of a form to an email.  Here's what I have.  I'm able to pront the contents as an array to my view, but not send the values to the email.

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $formData = array();
        $emailData = array();

    $form = new Application_Form_Contact();

        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {

                foreach ($formData as $d){
                    $emailData[] = $d;
                }

                 $mail = new Zend_Mail();

                 $mail->setFrom('me@me.com', 'user');
                 $mail->AddTo('me@me.com', 'joel');
                 $mail->setSubject('from form');
                 $mail->setBodyText($emailData);
                 $mail->send();

            } else {
                // bad stuff happens
            }
        }
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emailData needs to be a string.

```
$emailData = "Email content: ";
foreach ($formData as $d){
   $emailData .= $d . "\r\n";
}
```

Not the most elegant thing but it will work.

Comment: Man-thanks so much for this help and your earlier help!  All pieces are now in place and working!

Comment: hmm-what is strange is that the formData being emailed is not going through the validator even though when I view the form in the process view, it has stripped html, etc.  Idea why?

Comment: You know you should really just use it normally. If in your form you have a <input type="text" name="something" /> Then just use $emailData['something'] directly without looping thru it all.

Comment: Well, I wanted to create this as a generic form to use on a lot of my sites, so I just wanted to loop it.  I ended up just having to loop the getValues instead of formData and that worked out-I guess filtering only works on getValues